# Kim and Pearl's Message passing algorithm in Bayesian Network

Tags: c#, bayesian, bayesian-networks

Can you give me a good link/resource where i could find a good implementation of Bayesian network ,I'm specially interested in Conditional Probability Table generation and how to pass messages/update nodes .

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at

[Example of Bayesian network](http://community.research.microsoft.com/forums/t/2434.aspx)

and

[A Brief Introduction to Graphical Models and Bayesian Networks](http://people.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/bnintro.html)

Also, have a look at [Online Tutorials](http://www.decisionbasedlearning.org/DBLiWebSiteDev/OnlineTutorials/Default.aspx)